# Save WebSQL database as .sqlite

Tags: javascript

I am using WebSQL for a web project. I can view WebSQL databases using SQLite Manager. I learnt the database itself is saved in the browser's app data folder somewhere (using a funny file extension).

I was wondering if there was a way to save the WebSQL database as a .sqlite file and to specify the location where the file is saved(possibly).